# Bad auto completion with python on pydev?

Tags: python, pydev

I began learning and loving python about a month ago. Dive into python, django and now Tornado is the path i followed during this time.
I chose pydev as an IDE since it seems to be the most up to date and i wanted to come back to eclipse since i'm using Netbeans for php and Java.

My question is the following:
When i write classes in php or java i declare my methods and properties. I instantiate them somewhere else and use them. The autocompletion works great for java and php but with python, it seems to be always suggesting me a bunch of garbage and never the real object's methods from the class i instantiated.

Is it the same for you ? Is it a limitation from pydev ? Am i doing something wrong ?

Thank you in advance for pointing me in a direction.
Matthieu.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your [interpreter](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html) is set up correctly.

```
Window | Preferences | Pydev | Interpreter - Python
```

I use cpython on linux so my interpreter is

```
  cpython      /usr/bin/python25
```

Under Libraries, make sure all the standard PYTHONPATH stuff is in there:

```
System Libs
  /usr/lib/python2.5
  /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.5/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode
  /usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk
  /usr/lib/python25.zip
  etc....
```

You can also add any non standard paths here by clicking New Folder.

Do not add paths to your own source code though.  These should come in when you configure a pydev projec, select a "src" folder and start making modules, see [here](http://pydev.org/manual_101_first_module.html).

Comment: i'm checking my setup to verify your points. What i meant by garbage was that pydev autosuggest gave me a lot of results without any relation to the object i instantiated. Just like if it was giving me all methods from all classes it had in memory.

Comment: Well, i realized that all the classes i wrote were the reason of the msess since even the simple ones inherited from the object class. What's its purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm (http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/index.html) is much better than Pydev for auto completion, among other things.

Comment: PyCharm has the same problem, and it is not for free.

Comment: Not if you properly configure the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you didn't say what 'garbage' is showing, it's a bit hard to guess, but I believe you mean the `__hash__, __str__,` etc from the object class (is that it?)

If that's the case, this has been dealt in the current nightly build (the '_' methods will still appear, but with lower priority, so, the methods you're probably more interested in are at the top)