# New to PyDev, question about auto completion

Tags: python, pydev, code-completion

I installed Eclipse and PyDev and I'm wondering if I have to setup anything else?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm finding the auto complete isn't working in certain cases. For example, if I have a variable a_string, I'd like to see a list of available methods once I type "a_string." or if I have an array I'd like to see what methods it has. But neither one works atm.

Right now I can see methods from imported packages though.

Comment: I don't know about these tools, but I'm sure that in a language such a python it's very difficult to know the available methods or variables.

i.e., it's probably not possible to do what you want!

Comment: Not always can a list of available methods been shown, because pydev not necessarily knows, what kind of object you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work out of the box (given you configured your python interpreter path properly).

However, keep in mind that since Python is duck-typed you will not *necessarily* get the full auto-complete set you would expect from strongly-typed languages such as Java. Having said that, PyDev does do a good job with detecting easy scenarios to auto-complete, such as:

```
list = [1,2,3]
list. # auto-complete will recognize list is a list
```

Additionally, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470121/bad-auto-completion-with-python-on-pydev) for some more info.