# Eclipse wont import my enthought modules

Tags: python, eclipse, enthought

I have installed eclipse installed along with enthought. I can import my standard python modules no problem, but as soon as try to import my enthought modules I get an import error. I cant find the folder/location as to where the enthought modules are, so I can add that folder directly to eclipse.

Can someone point me as to where enthought installs the modules so I can add it to eclipses python path?

EDIT:

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.2
Using Python 2.7

Comment: did you already set the interpreter path in pydev ?

Comment: Yes I have I followed this tutorial. http://www.vogella.de/articles/Python/article.html#installation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469849/configuring-pydev-interpreter-in-eclipse-to-use-enthought-python-distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to install [pydev](http://pydev.org/), the Python plugin for Eclipse.
Because only with that the PYTHONPATH becomes manageable.
Then you need to go to Settings->Pydev->Python Interpreter and pick the python interpreter you are using (and that uses the correct path to find all the other EPD modules).

So, if for example you are using the newest Enthought 7.2, then your Python interpreter for that would be in:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/bin

In there you pick the python executable, and the Pydev plugin will then analyze all paths so that they will be known, even including automatic completions.

Comment: I have Enthought 7.1 should that make a difference?

Comment: Having 7.1 I dont see the 7.1 folder in the python frameworks folder

Comment: Sorry I read your answer wrong, I was looking in the wrong location

Comment: So I guess you found that you just replace 7.2 with 7.1 and it should work?